# Can the chi-square statistic in Kruskal-Wallis test be compared to determine the most appropriate to distinguish the groups?

Tags: chi-squared-test, group-differences, kruskal-wallis-test, metric, differences

I have a dataframe in R which format is similar as follows:

```
v1 v2  v3  group
1  3.5 100 a
3  5   200 a
10 5.5 150 b
8  7.5 210 b
4  4.5 300 c
9  2.5 200 c
...
```

My purpose is to decide **which metric (v1/v2/v3) is the most appropriate to distinguish the groups**(i.e. "a","b","c")? I have performed Kruskal-Wallis test for three varibles:

```
kruskal.test(v1 ~ group, data = df)
kruskal.test(v2 ~ group, data = df)
kruskal.test(v3 ~ group, data = df)
```

The results all show that v1/v2/v3 are sigificantly different between groups (p-value < 2.2e-16) but with different chi-squared:

```
kruskal.test(v1 ~ group, data = df)
```

> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 249.27, df = 5, p-value < 2.2e-16

```
kruskal.test(v2 ~ group, data = df)
```

> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 184.34, df = 5, p-value < 2.2e-16

```
kruskal.test(v3 ~ group, data = df)
```

> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 158.8, df = 5, p-value < 2.2e-16

Based on these results, could I infer that v1 is the most appropriate to distinguish the groups bewtween "a","b" and "c" since the chi-squared is the largest(249.27) among them?

Or if Kruskal-Wallis is not appropriate for determining the most appropriate metric to distinguish the groups? Which statistical methods should I use?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you mean by "appropriate" and how to assess degrees of "appropriateness"?

Comment: I admit that the "appropriate" here is a little vague. That is also where I am struggled with. From my perspective, for example, v1 is more appropriate than V2/V3 may mean that by using v1 the differences between groups A,B,C is more apparent/larger? I wonder whether chi-squared here is a good metric for quantifying this?

Comment: All three P-values are essentially $0,$ so you'd reject $H_0: \mathrm{no\; diff}$ at 5%. 1%. ..., 0.01% levels.

Comment: In general it is not valid to compare P-values.  But a bigger problem here is that the decision you hope to make from limited data are unlikely to replicate in other datasets.  Bootstrapping the entire selection process would demonstrate that.